# Assign new variable to smarty while in {php}

Tags: php, templates, smarty

Currently I am in a template and need {php} to read something from the Model/Database. This shall now be a new smarty variable within the current template. How do I solve this?

e.g.:

```
{php}
   $var["newSmartyVar"] = model_gimme_data();
   $currentTemplate->assign($var);
{/php}

The value is {$newSmartyVar} !
```

What's the correct code here?

(Yee, uncommon and not abstract but only needed for rapid prototyping. The code will go in the Controller later on.)

Comment: Mmm... Don't know if {capture} could help in this case.

Comment: Do not call models methods inside template. Call it outside, inside some PHP file and assign variable to the template. But, anyway, i think instead of `$currentTemplate` you should write `$this` and it will work

Comment: I can't believe how newer posts get acceptance while the first correct post get ignored. guys you should act fairly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this` refers to the current smarty instance:

```
{php}
$this->assign('foo', 'bar');
{/php}
{$foo}
```

you should, however, avoid {php} like the plague. Using {php} is a sign of missing abstraction. You could look into creating a function plugin instead.

Comment: Oh, it is in the object itself - nice! That's it, thanks! Yee, it lacks in abstraction but I got to prototype my issue in some way for the customer and wait for the project leader to come back from holiday to show me the right place in this very confusing code ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
{php}
global $currentTemplate;
$var = model_gimme_data();
$currentTemplate->assign('newSmartyVar',$var);
{/php}
```

to get something from the model:

```
{php}
global $currentTemplate;
$this->_tpl_vars['variableName'];
{/php}
```

Comment: Oh... `global` inside template it's amusingly=)